# Add Two TextViews In a TabView

Tags: java, android, tabs, textview, tabview

I am trying to get a similar tab layout to this one where there is the day of the week at the top and the day of the month on the bottom of the tab.
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE6iJ.jpg)

I just need some ideas on how to do this. I though of adding two TextViews in the tab but wasn't able to get that to work. Here is what I've got so far.

```html
private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setElevation(0);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupNumTab();
    }
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE", 1);
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO", 2);
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE", 3);
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR", 4);
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE", 5);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void setupNumTab() {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        TextView nameView = new TextView(this);
        nameView.setText("TEST");
        layout.addView(nameView);
        TextView anotherView = new TextView(this);
        anotherView.setText("12");
        layout.addView(anotherView);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use **TabLayout** and for each item, use customView.

And then attach it with the viewPager.

If you have many tabs to show, go for **fragmentStatePagerAdapter** or if you have only 2 or 3 tabs, use **fragmentPagerAdapter**. You can read about them more.

Do something like this...

Let's say this is your one mainActivity xml layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="61.8dp"
    android:background="#06acef"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
    android:fillViewport="false">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

   <ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ViewPager>
```

Their parent can be **LinearLayout** or say **RelativeLayout**. It's up to you how you do it.

Now, create one more layout for your tab. say **tab_layout.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:layout_below="@id/text2"
    android:id="@+id/show_time_tab_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now in your main activity..

inside **onCreate()** callback

```
   ViewPageAdapter viewPageAdapter = new ViewPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext(),this);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(viewPageAdapter);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

       // bind each tab data here
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            tab.setCustomView(viewPageAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }
```

Now, your ViewPageAdapter

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       return YoutFragment.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    public View getTabView(int position) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View tabView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_tab_layout, null, false);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text1.setText("text1");
        text2.setText("dateStr[1]");
        return tabView;
    }
}
```

And finally, your fragment, for each viewpagerAdapter, which is called inside **getItem()** callback.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{
      public static YourFragment newInstance(){
          return new YourFragment()
      }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was so much help, but I'm am getting some errors. First I setup my code like you had it in your reply, but now I'm getting an "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0" error when TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i); is called.

Comment: Yhay migth be because of the size of your arraylist in viewpager adapter.

Comment: ViewPager creates number of pages returned by you in getCount() callback and then it prepare it's items from getItem() callback. Use debugger or something or check the size of the array, which you are using.